# Does adding more replica to AWS elastic cache costs more?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, amazon-elasticache

we are using non cluster elastic cache **cache.m3.medium** which supports 0 - 5 replicas. I am trying to understand does it cost more if we add more replicas. e.g. cost of 1 primary node and 1 replica Vs 1 primary node and 2 replicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each replica has its own node. Each node will have its own instance hour cost.

1 primary + 2 replicas = 3 instances/hr

3 instances * $/instance hr will be the hourly cost.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/